# PHP Eclipse pass arguments as script

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I'm trying to debug `some_script.php` and want to pass `--some-parameter` in php script arguments tab. My script is started regularly, but I do not see `--some-parameter` in `$argv[1]`, which should be initialized.
My xdebug configuration for cli scripts include only one line:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
```

This is on Mac OS.

Comment: Have you checked out https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323931? Pay attention to comments 3 and 14.

Answer (score 0):

I set php.ini as follows:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug_remote_log
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=on
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t
;xdebug.collect_return=on
;xdebug.collect_vars=on
;xdebug.auto_trace=0
```

Then I restarted eclipse and is working now.